# Boost Spring Application run failed

Tags: java, mysql, spring, intellij-idea

Anyone help me, please? I am creating a job portal web application using spring boot and IDE: Intellij and the database are MYSQL. But when I run my application it gives me the error "2022-11-22 01:33:17.468 ERROR 30420 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed".
Here is my pom.xml file

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.onlinejobportal</groupId>
<artifactId>plateform</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>onlinejobportal</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repositories -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
   <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

   <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am going to attach the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArexR.png)error of the image below. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The screenshot lacks relevant information, that's why you are requested **not** to post screenshot of what could have been quoted text. Walk down the line of "Caused by" to identify why you configuration class "com.onlinejobportal.OnlinejobportalApplication" cannot be loaded.

Comment: "Anyone help me, please?" - You need to fix the question before anyone can help you.

Comment: It helps if you can also paste your minimal code here. Have you ensured your java version supported by Spring Boot 2.0.4? It is a common mistake for newbies.

Comment: There are no issues in your pom.xml. Can you paste your Spring config?